# Generate transparent circles in javascript (client side)

Tags: javascript, image, png, transparent

I'm implementing the routine to show icons of diferent sizes for markers in Google maps api, as shown in this page:
https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/maps/visualizing/earthquakes (look at the circles example):

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
    var earthquake = results.features[i];
    var coords = earthquake.geometry.coordinates;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag)
    });
  }
}

function getCircle(magnitude) {
  return {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    fillColor: 'red',
    fillOpacity: .2,
    scale: Math.pow(2, magnitude) / Math.PI,
    strokeColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: .5
  };
}
```

In chrome everything goes Ok, but when I do it in IE9 its painfully slow for many markers.
It has to be in IE9 because I'm automating IE9 in my app).
That's because IE9 works very slow with SVG.
So I'm trying a different approach, to use icons instead of SVG generated circles. For that I need to generate them on the fly, using JS (there is no server code in my project) and then saving the circles to disk and assign them to the marker.

How can I generate and save the circles as transparent PNGs, using only JS?

Comment: This could be achieved by generating Base64 encoded images and then using them as a data URI. Unfortunately this wouldn't be supported in IE9. Another option is to create the images on the backend (GD, Imagemagick), cache them, and serve on a request from the frontend. IE: /circle.php?radius=300

Comment: If IE9 supports `<canvas>`, this should easily be possible. And [yes, it does](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)!

Comment: Thanks. Since the icons will be limited to 300px, I'll generate the icons and save them on a directory . I just tested it and the performance improvement is amazing, a hundred times faster